Transform for loop with if else condition to a more efficient implementation in R
I have implemented the combination of for loop and if else condition in R
for (i in 1:n) {
  if(some condition) {
    some code
  else {
    some code
  }
}

The condition is the i-th element of a vector is lower than a certain threshold. And I perform some different operation on it depending whether it is true or false. The vector is very long and I would like to know if there is a way to perform this without using for loop.

use ifelse() it is vectorized so you do not need a loop

It is something that will ALWAYS depend on the operation you want to evaluate. For example: if you wanted to evaluate if element myvector[i] is a multiple of 7 you could either use that conditional scheme and go element by element or you could use a function like myvector[i] %% 7 == 0. In short, if you are looking for a precise answer to your question, I suggest you specify what that some code operation is. Remember that in R loops of that type are relatively slow.

There isn't enough information to answer this reliably but in general you have to loop through the vector to test each element and then apply the right computation to it. What you have is pretty much the minimal canonical form unless "some code1" and "some code2" can be factored out into common code and specific to true/false paths. If n was small then unrolling the loop might be an option.

Here are some benchmarks for you.

vec <- rep(c(1:5,5:1),1000)


f1 <- \(x){
  9 * (x < 3) + 7 * (x >= 3)
}
f2 <- \(x){
  for (i in seq_along(x)) {
    if (x[i] < 3) {
     x[i] <- 9
    } else {
      x[i] <- 7
    }
  }
  x
}

f3 <- \(x){
  if(x<3)
    return(9)
  else 
    return( 7)
}

f4 <- \(x){
  ifelse(x<3,9,7)
}

bench::mark(
  vec_direct=f1(vec),
  vec_forloop=f2(vec),
  vec_sapply=sapply(vec,f3),
  vec_ifelse=f4(vec)
)

# A tibble: 4 × 13
  expression       min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time
  <bch:expr>  <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm>
1 vec_direct    38.9µs   45.5µs    16022.   264.5KB    79.9   5015    25      313ms
2 vec_forloop  684.1µs  702.6µs     1344.    78.2KB     2.03   661     1      492ms
3 vec_sapply    3.93ms   4.27ms      225.   362.6KB     6.42   105     3      468ms
4 vec_ifelse   118.8µs 162.25µs     4908.   555.3KB    55.9   1668    19      340ms

the iterations/sec column

If you're going to benchmark such a simple operation, I'd strongly suggest increasing the size of the input so it's large enough for the differences to be more meaningful. On my machine, I ran your code with rep(c(1:5,5:1), 1e5) and the order of the results is quite different, with vec_direct the quickest, followed closely by vec_ifelse, then vec_forloop about 2x slower, then vec_sapply about 10x slower.

Ooops, I just missed the ms vs µs in the median column, guess that's actually pretty comparable overall.  All the same, measurements in µs are rarely very precise. Unless the context is exactly that, bigger inputs for benchmarking are usually both more reliable measurements and in the common case where algorithms scale differently, more applicable to the size of inputs where efficiency matters.

I tend to focus on itr/sec column

Here is a simple demonstration of how to apply a condition to the elements of a vector without using a for loop:
num_vec <- c(5,2,4,6,1,7)

multiply <- function(x){
  if(x >= 5){
    return(x * 2)
  }else{
    return(0)
  }
}

vec_process <- sapply(num_vec,multiply)

print(vec_process)

10  0  0 12  0 14

In the above example, we write a function that doubles a value if it is greater than or equal to 5, otherwise, the function returns 0.
Next, we iteratively apply that function to all the elements in the vector num_vec using sapply() to get a new vector vec_process, which contains the new values that have been conditionally created.
I hope this simple example helps!
